# error for ppa stating can not add ppa, lock on dpkg and archives

Tags: ubuntu

This error is being shown while trying to use webup8team for installing wine and sublime.

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webup8team/ubuntu/sublime-text-3'. ERROR: '~webup8team' user or team does not exist.
```

Comment: show error in detail and command you have fired

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra '~' in the ppa. The correct ppa repo is ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3

Try with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```